# Data encrypted with mbedtls not decrypting properly with Bouncy Castle

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, bouncycastle, mbedtls

I have a microcontroller using mbedtls to encrypt data, which is transmitted to a Windows computer where it must be decrypted using Bouncy Castle. AES256 in CBC mode, with a 16-byte initialization vector, is used.  My data will always be multiples of the AES block size (16 bytes), so padding is not needed.  The encryption code is:

```
int Crypto_Encrypt_Data(unsigned char* data, int num_bytes, unsigned char* ct, unsigned char* IniVec)
{
  unsigned char iv[16];

  //Load the AES key into the AES context; specify key size in bits (NOT bytes)
  mbedtls_aes_setkey_enc( &AES_Context, (unsigned char*)AESKey, (key_size * 8) );

  //Load the initialization vector with a random number
  mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random( &DRBG_Context, iv, strlen((char*)iv) );

  //Save a copy of the IV for possible use decrypting
  memcpy(InitializationVector, iv, 16);

  //Return a copy of the IV to caller
  *IniVec = *InitializationVector;

  return mbedtls_aes_crypt_cbc( &AES_Context, MBEDTLS_AES_ENCRYPT, num_bytes, iv, data, ct );
}
```

On the Windows side, the decryption code is:

```
 public static byte[] CBCDecryptData(FipsAes.Key key, byte[] ciphertext, byte[] iv)
    {
        IBlockCipherService provider = CryptoServicesRegistrar.CreateService(key);
        IBlockCipherBuilder<IParameters<Algorithm>> decryptBuilder = provider.CreateBlockDecryptorBuilder(FipsAes.Cbc.WithIV(iv));
    IBlockCipher decryptor = decryptBuilder.BuildBlockCipher(new MemoryInputStream(ciphertext));

    byte[] plaintext;
    using (Stream decryptorStream = decryptor.Stream)
    {
        plaintext = Streams.ReadAll(decryptorStream);
    }
    return plaintext;
}
```

I have verified that the initialization vector and cipher text on the Windows side is the same as that in the microcontoller, but the decrypted plain text does not match, see below:

```
Microcontroller, mbedtls
Key: 4D:A6:E2:9D:AF:25:58:75:EE:5C:70:88:55:BA:4F:62:07:FE:B1:8A:58:59:91:FE:B3:3D:66:B7:DA:EF:2F:60
iv: 42:00:E0:0F:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:4A:FB:00:00:00
Plain Text: 54:68:69:73:20:68:65:72:65:20:69:73:20:61:6E:20:65:6E:63:72:79:70:74:69:6F:6E:20:74:65:73:74:2E
Cipher Text: 2D:6D:AB:63:BE:10:3D:87:AA:15:41:7C:8F:E5:16:81:AF:D9:E0:92:3E:37:DF:92:C4:15:41:55:7B:FD:0B:6B

Windows, Bouncy Castle
Key: 4D:A6:E2:9D:AF:25:58:75:EE:5C:70:88:55:BA:4F:62:07:FE:B1:8A:58:59:91:FE:B3:3D:66:B7:DA:EF:2F:60
iv: 42:00:E0:0F:00:00:01:00:00:00:01:4A:FB:00:00:00
Cipher Text: 2D:6D:AB:63:BE:10:3D:87:AA:15:41:7C:8F:E5:16:81:AF:D9:E0:92:3E:37:DF:92:C4:15:41:55:7B:FD:0B:6B
Plain Text: 54:EA:89:7C:20:68:64:72:65:20:68:39:FB:61:6E:20:65:6E:63:72:79:70:74:69:6F:6E:20:74:65:73:74:2E
```

I notice that the last (second) 16-bytes (one AES block) appears to decrypt OK, but not the first. This is probably a clue to the problem, but I can not figure out what it is. Also, the data does decrypt OK using mbedtls in the microcontroller.

Comment: That is really strange. Typically when a decryption goes wrong, the entire output is garbage. Getting just a few bytes in the first block wrong is bizarre. I agree with Topaco this looks like an IV mismatch. I would plug this into a third implementation and see which one is wrong. (You didn't provide a key, so we can't check your work easily.)

Comment: Are you sure that the correct IV was used when decrypting with BouncyCastle? A wrong IV is reflected in AES/CBC by a corrupted first block (while the rest of the blocks are decrypted correctly).

Comment: I updated the data to include the AES key.  I will take another look at the IV, but as shown above it appears to be the same on both sides (mbedtls and BC).  I did try reversing the order of the IV bytes on the BC side - in case there was an endianess difference - but things got worse.

Comment: FYI, I dumped this into the following tool (it was the first I found online that would let me do everything in hex), and the decryption matches, but the encryption doesn't, making me suspect the mbedtls side. https://the-x.cn/en-us/cryptography/Aes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The problem was indeed with the IV. Being quite rusty regarding pointers/arrays, I was not passing back the IV correctly.  On the microcontroller side, giving the calling function access to the InitializationVector array allowed the correct IV to be sent to the Bouncy Castle decryption routine on the Windows side - which now produces the correct result.

The encryption routine in the microcontroller simplifies a bit to become:

```
int Crypto_Encrypt_Data(unsigned char* data, int num_bytes, unsigned char* ct)
{
  unsigned char iv[16];

  //Load the AES key into the AES context; specify key size in bits (NOT bytes)
  mbedtls_aes_setkey_enc( &AES_Context, (unsigned char*)AESKey, (key_size * 8) );

  //Load the initialization vector with a random number
  mbedtls_ctr_drbg_random( &DRBG_Context, iv, strlen((char*)iv) );

  //Save a copy of the IV, to be used for decryption
  memcpy(InitializationVector, iv, 16);

  return mbedtls_aes_crypt_cbc( &AES_Context, MBEDTLS_AES_ENCRYPT, num_bytes, iv, data, ct );
}
```

Since mbedtls_aes_crypt_cbc() modifies iv, the copy saved in InitializationVector is sent, along with the cipher text, ct, to the Windows side where Bouncy Castle can successfully decrypt it.